# Build an inverted array of dates

Tags: ruby

I have given list of dates like this:

```
['2020-02-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-08']
```

I want the inverse of this range like this (the missing dates in that range):

```
['2020-02-02', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-04', '2020-02-06', '2020-02-07']
```

I am sure I can build some sort of loop that starts at the first date then iterates through to build that second array.  Any chance there is a ruby method / trick to do this faster?

Comment: A) Generate the dates in that range. B) Use `Array#-` as in `[ ... ] - [ ... ]` to remove the ones you don't want. C) This would be easier if using Ruby `Date` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#difference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-difference) or [Array#-](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-2D) on range of Date objects. For example, with Ruby 2.7.1:

```
require "date"

dates = ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-08']

# convert sorted strings to date objects
dates.sort.map! { Date.strptime _1, "%Y-%m-%d" }

# use first and last date to build an array of dates
date_range = (dates.first .. dates.last).to_a

# remove your known dates from the range - dates).map &:to_s
(date_range - dates).map &:to_s
#=> ["2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-07"]
```

For compactness, and assuming your date strings in *dates* are already sorted, you could also use a train wreck like this:

```
((dates[0]..dates[-1]).to_a - dates).map &:to_s
```

Comment: what does this line mean? ` Date.strptime _1, "%Y-%m-%d"`  Why used _1? I don't find syntax like that. It's throwing the error. You could use Date.parse to convert string into Date object.

Comment: @Rajagopalan `_1` is a so-called _numbered parameter_ referring to the block's first parameter. They were introduced in Ruby 2.7 as an attempt to simplify certain code patterns. The original idea was quite lovely: to use `it` or `this`, e.g. `Date.strptime(this, ...)` but then they became `_1`, `_2` etc. So instead of code that speaks for itself, we know have more cryptic code. (you might have guessed it: I dislike this language addition) You can just use `dates.sort.map! { |d| Date.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") }` instead.

Comment: @Stefan You are really helpful all the time. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Date#parse isn't always the right choice, but neither is Date#strptime. It just depends on your needs and your data. Date#parse is a lot more likely to raise Date::Error when a date doesn't strictly conform to an expected input format, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

arr = ['2020-02-26', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-04']

first, last = arr.map { |s| Date.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d') }.minmax
  #=> [#<Date: 2020-02-26 ((2458906j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<Date: 2020-03-04 ((2458913j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>] 
(first..last).map { |d| d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') } - arr 
  #=> ["2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01",
  #    "2020-03-03"]
```

See [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [Date#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array#min, Array#max and Array#- to easily solve this:

```
dates = ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-05', '2020-02-08']
missing_dates = ((dates.min..dates.max).to_a) - dates
=> [‘2020-02-02’, ‘2020-02-03’, ‘2020-02-04’, ‘2020-02-06’, ‘2020-02-07’]
```

Comment: What about `dates = ['2020-01-29', '2020-02-02']`?

Comment: As a nitpick, while `dates.min..dates.max` is  perfectly valid, I'd probably use more whitespace to make it easier to visually scan the second line. For example, `dates.min .. dates.max` makes it *visually* easier to see that we're creating a range with two objects. Otherwise, it's a very nice way to avoid an explicit sort call in the method chain.

Comment: The problem here is that if you go to the next month on a larger span the `dates.min..dates.max` returns days of the week all the way to 99 then starts at 00 again.

Comment: In that case, one of the other answers is probably better.